# Harmony of the Gospels (earlier versions)

Tags: reference-request, gospels

Following is the introduction to *A Harmony of the Gospels,* by A.T. Robertson. Does anyone know the titles/authors/publication dates of the previous "old plan" harmonies? Augustine wrote a book by that title in the 5th century. Robertson wrote in the early 1900s. I am looking for the (English) versions in between. The best I've been able to manage are some leads on Goodreads [here](https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=harmony%20of%20the%20gospels&qid=), but I'm hoping someone has some more knowledge about 'pre-Robertson' harmonies. Thanks!

*It is now just thirty years since one day his young assistant suggested to Dr. John A. Broadus that he prepare a harmony of the Gospels that should depart from the old plan of following the feasts as the turning points in the life of Jesus. He acted on the hint and led the way that all modern harmonies have followed. The book has gone through a dozen large editions and has become the standard harmony for many thousands of students all over the world.*

[Here](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/471365) is another explanation of Robertson's (and Broadus's) approach. Titles I'm looking into:

• The Fourfold Gospel (J.W. McGarvey)
• The Diatessaron-A Harmony of the Gospels (Tatian the Assyrian)
• The Harmony of the Gospels (Augustine)
• A Harmony of the Gospels: Matthew, Mark and Luke (John Calvin)
• Horizontal Harmony of the Four Gospels in Parallel Columns (Thomas M. Mumford)